# ¿Cómo validar solo numero en un DataGridView?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagrid

Tengo un `DataGridView` y quiero que en ciertas columnas solo deje ingresar números

Esta es mi tabla:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < tblarticulo.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
 {
      cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("pro_factura", conexion, transaccion);
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      cmd.Parameters.Clear();
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_codigod", Convert.ToInt32(tblarticulo.Rows[i].Cells["column1"].Value));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_descripcion", Convert.ToString(tblarticulo.Rows[i].Cells["column2"].Value));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_cantidad", Convert.ToInt32(tblarticulo.Rows[i].Cells["column3"].Value));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_precio", Convert.ToInt32(tblarticulo.Rows[i].Cells["column4"].Value));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_valtotal", Convert.ToInt32(tblarticulo.Rows[i].Cells["column5"].Value));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_codigo", Convert.ToInt32(tblarticulo.Rows[i].Cells["column6"].Value = codigofactura.Text));
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Hola bienvenido a StackOverFlow, mira [ask], para que en futuras preguntas hagas una mejor elaboración de la misma, además te invito a hacer el [tour] para que comprendas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 3):

**Método #1:**

Una manera un tanto sencilla en la que puedes lograr esto es:

- Agregar un evento de `EditingControlShowing`
- En `EditingControlShowing`, verifique si la celda actual se encuentra en la columna deseada.
- Registre un nuevo evento de `KeyPress` en `EditingControlShowing` (si la condición anterior es verdadera).
- Elimine cualquier evento `KeyPress` agregado previamente en `EditingControlShowing`.
- En el evento `KeyPress`, verifique que si la clave no es un dígito, cancele la entrada.

Ejemplo:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0 |
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1 |
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2) //Columnas deseadas
    {
        TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
        if (tb != null)
        {
            tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Columns_KeyPress);
        }
    }
}

private void Columns_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

> Como menciona que son 3 columnas que desea que acepten números, esta parte:
>
> `if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0 |
>        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1 |
>        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2)`
>
> Está indicando que las tres primeras columnas solo aceptarán números, puede cambiar usted sus columnas deseadas. O bien si desea identificarla por el nombre de las columnas puede usar:
>
> `if( dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["NombreColumna"].Index)`
>
> O de esta manera:
>
> `string nombreColumna =  dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name; 
>   if(nombreColumna == "Column1" | nombreColumna == "Column2" | nombreColumna == "Column3")`
>
> De la manera que más lo entienda o convenga...

---

**Método #2:**

Esto puede conllevar muchos casos de validación es por ello, que voy a recomendarte que uses este código creado por el usuario [Asier Villanueva](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6088/asier-villanueva), que se encuentra en el siguiente enlace: [Windows Forms. DataGridView. Columna que acepta sólo números.](http://pildorasdotnet.blogspot.com/2015/04/datagridview-columna-solo-numeros.html)

El cual consiste en crear una Biblioteca de clases que extiende de `DataGridView` para poder obtener acceso a sus propiedades, luce de la siguiente manera:

`IntegerGridColumn.cs` en el que se va definir dos clases. La clase `IntegerGridColumn` que hereda de `DataGridViewColumn` y la clase `IntegerGridCell` que hereda de `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GridExtension
{
    public class IntegerGridColumn : DataGridViewColumn
    {
    }

    public class IntegerGridCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    {
    }
}
```

En la clase `IntegerGridCell` se sobreescribe la propiedad `ValueType` para especificar que el tipo de los valores de la celda es `Int32`, y el método `InitializeEditingControl` para añadir un controlador de evento al evento `KeyPress` del control de edición de la celda.

El controlador de este evento (el método `IntegerGridCell_KeyPress`) va a ser el responsable de controlar que los caracteres se correspondan con caracteres numéricos. En caso contrario establece la propiedad `Handled` del objeto `KeyPressEventArgs` a true para anular el tratamiento de la tecla pulsada.

```
public class IntegerGridCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{

    public IntegerGridCell() : base() { }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
         get { return typeof(Int32); }
    }

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);
        Control ctl = DataGridView.EditingControl;
        ctl.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(IntegerGridCell_KeyPress);
    }

    private void IntegerGridCell_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCell currentCell = ((IDataGridViewEditingControl)sender).EditingControlDataGridView.CurrentCell;
        if (currentCell is IntegerGridCell)
            e.Handled = !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar);
    }
}
```

En el constructor de la clase `IntegerGridColumn` llamar al constructor de `DataGridViewColumn` pasándole una instancia de `IntegerGridCell` como plantilla de celda. Y sobreescribir también la propiedad `CellTemplate` para comprobar que la celda que se establece como plantilla es del tipo `IntegerGridCell`.

```
public class IntegerGridColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
     public IntegerGridColumn() : base(new IntegerGridCell()) { }

     public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
     {
         get
         {
             return base.CellTemplate;
         }
         set
         {
             if (value != null &&
                 !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IntegerGridCell)))
                 throw new InvalidCastException("Debe ser del tipo IntegerGridCell");
             base.CellTemplate = value;
         }
     }
 }
```

Para su uso te saldría así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Para ver la información mas detallada de como se usa, debes visitar el enlace indicado en la respuesta.

**Nota:**  *He colocado los códigos tal cual esta descrito en el link para no colocar una respuesta solo haciendo referencia a un link*  **Todos los créditos para Asier**

Comment: amigo, el problema es que yo estoy haciendo todo en el form y necesito que apenas sean 3 columnas las que no dejen ingresar letras

Comment: @user156166 Y cual es el problema?, con esto puedes hacer que esas 3 columnas que dices acepten número, estoy seguro que no has intentado hacerlo con este código

Comment: pues  la verdad no lo comprendo mucho

Comment: @user156166 Visita el enlace y **lee el documento completo**, y hazlo paso a paso, porque desde un vistazo simple, no vas a entender.

Comment: bueno, Gracias!!

Comment: @user156166 y veo que no has hecho caso a hacer el [tour], deberías hacerlo para que entiendas como funciona StackOverFlow :)

Comment: pase por la pagina pero no lo entendí me parece confuso

Comment: @user156166 en la página al final hay un enlace para descargar el proyecto de ejemplo, descárgalo y pruebalo para que entiendas

Comment: ese link no muestra nada

Comment: @user156166 Si el link no esta disponible solo lea del documento paso a paso el cual lo guia a como crear el proyecto de ejemplo, esta aplicado como hacerlo, es que esta tratando de correr sin aprender a caminar, tome un momento en seguir la guía, cree el proyecto y haga las pruebas y luego trabajalo en tu proyecto principal

Comment: @user156166 he editado mi respuesta, he colocado un nuevo método que será mas fácil para ti entender, úsalo.